# how to retrieve multiple named subcomponents (as.list) of a function applied to a dplyr grouped data and save them in multiple variables in one go?

Tags: r, dplyr

I want to apply normalmixEM function in R to every group of data using dplyr group_by function and retreive some of the results variables in related column names at one go. I can do this by applying normalmixEM as many time as I want to retrieve a single result and save it to a column using mutate function but I want to apply normalmixEM only once and retrieve all the needed results to the intended columns.

I have tried the following which is not what I want to do:

```
    data2 = data1 %>% 
      group_by(criteria1, criteria2) %>% 
      mutate(mu1 = normalmixEM(Value)$mu[1], 
             mu2 = normalmixEM(Value)$mu[2],
         lambda1 = normalmixEM(Value)$lambda[1],
         lambda2 = normalmixEM(Value)$lambda[2])
```

I want to apply normalmixEM only once per group and save the results to the intended new cols then go to the next group.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `group_by()` and `reframe()` where the output in `reframe()` is a data frame that collects the relevant objects from the `normalmixEM()` output. At the end, you can `unnest()` the output column.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(mixtools)
mtcars %>% 
  group_by(cyl)  %>% 
  reframe(out = {n <- normalmixEM(qsec) 
  data.frame(mu1 = n$mu[1], 
             mu2=n$mu[2], 
             lambda1 = n$lambda[1], 
             lambda2 = n$lambda[2])}) %>% 
  unnest(out) %>% 
  right_join(mtcars)
#> One of the variances is going to zero;  trying new starting values.
#> number of iterations= 22 
#> number of iterations= 19 
#> number of iterations= 8
#> Joining with `by = join_by(cyl)`
#> # A tibble: 32 × 15
#>      cyl   mu1   mu2 lambda1 lambda2   mpg  disp    hp  drat    wt  qsec    vs
#>    <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#>  1     4  19.0  19.2   0.498   0.502  22.8 108      93  3.85  2.32  18.6     1
#>  2     4  19.0  19.2   0.498   0.502  24.4 147.     62  3.69  3.19  20       1
#>  3     4  19.0  19.2   0.498   0.502  22.8 141.     95  3.92  3.15  22.9     1
#>  4     4  19.0  19.2   0.498   0.502  32.4  78.7    66  4.08  2.2   19.5     1
#>  5     4  19.0  19.2   0.498   0.502  30.4  75.7    52  4.93  1.62  18.5     1
#>  6     4  19.0  19.2   0.498   0.502  33.9  71.1    65  4.22  1.84  19.9     1
#>  7     4  19.0  19.2   0.498   0.502  21.5 120.     97  3.7   2.46  20.0     1
#>  8     4  19.0  19.2   0.498   0.502  27.3  79      66  4.08  1.94  18.9     1
#>  9     4  19.0  19.2   0.498   0.502  26   120.     91  4.43  2.14  16.7     0
#> 10     4  19.0  19.2   0.498   0.502  30.4  95.1   113  3.77  1.51  16.9     1
#> # ℹ 22 more rows
#> # ℹ 3 more variables: am <dbl>, gear <dbl>, carb <dbl>
```

<sup>Created on 2023-10-06 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Thank you @DaveArmstrong for the great help. Then how to add this new columns to the old data(mtcars)?

Comment: Adding `right_join(mtcars)` to the end will do it.  I edited the answer.

Comment: Brilliant @DaveArmstrang